# Querying with Mongoose by a field

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to query on this mongoose object '*Order*' in express. However, when I add in the *querystring* variable between the parentheses on *find*, it doesn't work. I'm a bit lost on the documentation on how to resolve this issue.

```
router.get('/allorders', jwtAuth, function(req,res,next) {
    const userID = req.user.username;
    const querystring = "{orderedByUser: '" + userID + "'}";

//Order.find() works

Order.find(querystring)
.then(orders =>{
     res.json(orders).end();
}).catch( err=> {
    res.status(500).json({error: 'Something went wrong!'});
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know why, because the condition you need to pass to the `Model.find()` must be an `object`:

> **Model.find()**
>
> *Parameters*
>
> - conditions «Object»
> - [projection] «Object|String» optional fields to return, see    Query.prototype.select()
> - [options] «Object» optional see Query.prototype.setOptions()
> - [callback] «Function»
>
> *Returns*
>
> - «Query»
>
> Finds documents

For example:

```
// named john and at least 18
MyModel.find({ name: 'john', age: { $gte: 18 }});

// executes immediately, passing results to callback
MyModel.find({ name: 'john', age: { $gte: 18 }}, function (err, docs) {});
```

In your codes, you're passing a `string` to that method instead of an `object`.

Then, try this:

```js
router.get('/allorders', jwtAuth, function(req,res,next) {
    const userID = req.user.username;
    const conditionsObject = {orderedByUser: userID}; // fixed

//Order.find() works

Order.find(conditionsObject) // fixed
.then(orders =>{
     res.json(orders).end();
}).catch( err=> {
    res.status(500).json({error: 'Something went wrong!'});
      });
});
```

For more information about `Model.find()` method, you could read it here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`find` accepts a query *object*, not a string. So it should be:

```
Order.find({orderedByUser: userID}).then(...
```